# Populate properties of an object from several SQL selects asynchronously C#

Tags: c#, object, asynchronous, properties

I have an object with several properties, each populated from a separate SQL select statement. I want to execute the select statements at the same time but wait to return the entire object until each property has data. I am very new to async in c# and I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around it. This is an example of how I would accomplish this synchronously.

```
public MyObj GetMyObj()
{
    MyObj obj = new MyObj();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select ...";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            obj.Prop1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select ...";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            obj.Prop2 = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

I would ideally like to create task methods for each of these select blocks and wait to return the full Object once complete (my basic understanding is from the [Microsoft Async article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)):

```
public MyObj GetMyObj()
{
    MyObj obj = new MyObj();

    var prop1Task = GetProp1();
    var prop2Task = GetProp2();

    var allTasks = new List<Task>{prop1Task, prop2Task};
    while (allTasks.Any())
    {
        Task finished = await Task.WhenAny(allTasks);
        if (finished == prop1Task)
        {
            allTasks.Remove(prop1Task);
            obj.Prop1 = await prop1Task;
        } else if (finished == prop2Task)
        {
            allTasks.Remove(prop2Task);
            obj.Prop2 = await prop2Task;
        } else
                allTasks.Remove(finished);
    }

    return obj;
}

private async Task<int> GetProp1()
{
    int prop1 = 0;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select ...";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            prop1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }

    return prop1;
}
```

When building the `GetProp1()` method I get an intellisense warning that "*This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously*".

Am I executing the individual 'GetProp' methods correctly? Is the intellisense warning wrong? I am executing several select statements so changing this operation to run asynchronously would greatly increase performance.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you are looking to return `Task<int>` from your `GetProp1()` method, then just remove the `async` since it rightfully tells you that you don't have any `await`s and replace `return prop1;` with `return Task.FromResult(prop1);`. This will now be awaitable method

Comment: I would execute all the commands together with an ExecuteReader and then look at the various results with the NextResult method from the SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is executing asynchronously in `GetProp1`. The warning means exactly what it says; there is a method marked as `async` that is not doing anything asynchronously, so it is going to execute synchronously. Rewrite your `GetPropX` methods to use the asynchronous methods on `SqlConnection` / `SqlCommand`.

```csharp
private async Task<int> GetProp1()
{
    int prop1 = 0;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        await con.OpenAsync();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select ...";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            prop1 = await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        }
    }

    return prop1;
}
```

That said, if the various select statements are all being executed against the same database you could just execute multiple statements at once, use `ExecuteReader` and `NextResult`.

Something like this...

```csharp
private async Task<MyObj> GetMyObjAsync()
{
   MyObj obj = new MyObj();
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
   {
      await con.OpenAsync();
      string sqlStatements = @"
SELECT Prop1 FROM Table1;
SELECT Prop2 FROM Table2;
SELECT Prop3 FROM Table3;
--etc";

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatements, con))
      using (SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
      {
         if (await reader.ReadAsync()) 
         {
            obj.Prop1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Prop1"]);
         }
         await reader.NextResultAsync();
         if (await reader.ReadAsync()) 
         {
            obj.Prop2 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Prop2"]);
         }
         await reader.NextResultAsync();
         if (await reader.ReadAsync()) 
         {
            obj.Prop3 = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Prop3"]);
         }
         // etc...
      }
   }
   return obj;
}
```

This way, you only have one connection to the database instead of having to create a separate connection per property on `MyObj`.

Comment: Went with the second suggestion. Thanks!